# Does nodejs natively take advantage of multi-core processors?

Tags: node.js

My understanding of nodejs is that it is single-threaded.  I take this to mean that if you run a single instance of a nodejs application it will run on only one core of the processor leaving the others idle unless you invoke a worker process.  However, I once tested this out by running a nodejs web app (behind an nginx proxy) on a four core processor.  At full load, I was surprised to see usage across all CPU cores.  Do I have a misunderstanding of how nodejs should use CPU cores?

Comment: Nginx will typically fan out to multiple Node processes automatically, taking advantage of extra cores. There's also [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) to have multiple threads per process.

Comment: I was not using worker threads so that could not have been it.  As for nginx, what do you mean it will "fan out to multiple Node processes automatically"?  If the nginx proxy target is a Node app, how does nginx create multiple processes?  Wouldn't nginx just funnel all requests to that single Node process?

Comment: @tadman - NGINX does not automatically fan out to multiple nodejs process unless you configure it to do so and make sure you start up multiple nodejs processes.  This is not somethiong NGINX knows how to do without you creating that configuration and starting the separate server processes, each on their own port and then telling NGINX what ports you're using.  Here's some NGINX [doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-controller/platform/manage-cluster/) on clustering.

Comment: @jfriend00 Bare Nginx, no, but most Node deployments use something like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/nodejs/fundamental_concepts.html).

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding of nodejs is that it is single-threaded. I take this to mean that if you run a single instance of a nodejs application it will run on only one core of the processor leaving the others idle unless you invoke a worker process.

Nodejs does run YOUR Javascript in a single thread.  But, nodejs itself uses threads for things such as cryptography and disk I/O that your Javascript may call and because these functions are non-blocking, asynchronous interfaces, other parts of your Javascript can run during those operations.  And, nodejs also uses some threads for its own internal implementation.  If you fire up a nodejs server and examine what resources it's using, you will see it has multiple threads (I forget the exact count last time I looked, but it was in the range of 6-9 threads on Windows 11).

And, if you have a database involved in your server, then it will use additional threads/CPUs.

NGINX itself will also use one or more threads.  So, you have a 4 core CPU and nodejs itself will use several threads and you have NGINX that can easily use multiple threads.  And, if there's a database involved, it can use threads.
It's not hard to see how 4 cores could easily be busy with a nodejs server.

That said, the usual way to take maximal advantage of many cores is to either move CPU-intensive code to WorkerThreads in nodejs or to use some form of clustering either through NGINX, some other load balancer or using the nodejs clustering module.